# How can I use a list of commands as rows in a longtable?

Tags: tables, macros, longtable

If I "hardwire" the rows of the `longtable` environment it works almost as I want. But, if I try to use commands, LaTeX says missing `}` and hangs.

I want to use commands in the arguments to the `\TestProcedure` command to minimize work for authors and maximize document automation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setcounter{LTchunksize}{1000}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}% to define requirements list for TOC,F,T
%local variables for the \TestProc macro command
\newcounter{TestProcItemCounter}
\newcounter{NTPRC}
%new list for test procedures
\newlistof[NTPRC]{testprocedure}{tpr}{\listtestproceduresname}
\newcommand{\numberedtestprocedure}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{testprocedure}%
\addcontentsline{tpr}{testprocedure}{\protect\numberline{#1}#2}\par}
% declaration of a command, with junk so I can see if it didn;t get set
\newcommand{\ThisTestProcNum}{?!?num} %this gets set and reset in \TestProc[6]
\newcommand{\ThisTestProcName}{?!?name} %this gets set and reset in \TestProc[6]
\newcommand{\ThisTestProcLabel}{?!?label} %this gets set and reset in \TestProc[6]
%
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}%
\setlength{\hoffset}{0in}%
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% beginning of Test Procedure Macro
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% the macros used within the \TestProcedure[6] macro to make things easier for test writers 
% from below to compare \stepcounter{TestProcItemCounter}~R-\ThisTestProcNum-\theTestProcItemCounter & \parbox[top][12pt][c]{5.0in}{Hardcoded Requirement 1} \\ \hline%
\newcommand{\tpRqmt}[1]{\stepcounter{TestProcItemCounter}~R-\ThisTestProcNum-\theTestProcItemCounter & \parbox[top][12pt][c]{5.0in}{#1} \\ \hline}
%
% from below to compare \stepcounter{TestProcItemCounter}~S-\ThisTestProcNum-\theTestProcItemCounter & \parbox[top][42pt][t]{5in}{\vspace{2pt}Hardcoded Step 1} \\ \hline%
\newcommand{\tpStep}[2]{\stepcounter{TestProcItemCounter}~S-\ThisTestProcNum-\theTestProcItemCounter & \parbox[top][  #2][t]{5.0in}{\vspace{2pt}{#1}} \\ \hline}
%
% from below to compare \stepcounter{TestProcItemCounter}~N-\ThisTestProcNum-\theTestProcItemCounter & \parbox[top][12pt][c]{5in}{Hardcoded Note 1} \\ \hline%
\newcommand{\tpNote}[1]{\stepcounter{TestProcItemCounter}~N-\ThisTestProcNum-\theTestProcItemCounter & \parbox[top][12pt][c]{5.0in}{#1} \\ \hline}
%
\newcommand{\TestProcedure}[6]{%
% variables to avoid confusion between the #1, #2, and #3 args to \TestProcedure[6], which is also needed in \tpRqmt[1], \tpStep[2], and \tpNote[1]
\renewcommand{\ThisTestProcNum}{#1}% store away the test description number for use in the macro
\renewcommand{\ThisTestProcName}{#2}% store away the test description name for use in the macros
\renewcommand{\ThisTestProcLabel}{#3}% store away the test description label for use in the macros
%
% may need to run LaTeX three (3) times to get column widths correct, per LongTable documentation !
%
\begin{longtable}[l]{|r|l|}% base table has two columns <item number & item text>
%
\hline \hline%
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\parbox[top][12pt][c]{\textwidth}{{\centering \bf Test Procedure \ThisTestProcNum \numberedtestprocedure{\ThisTestProcNum}{\ThisTestProcName}}}}\\%
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\parbox[top][12pt][c]{\textwidth}{\centering \bf \ThisTestProcName}\label{\ThisTestProcLabel}}\\%
\hline \hline%
\endfirsthead%

\hline \hline%
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\parbox[top][12pt][c]{\textwidth}{\centering \bf Test Procedure \ThisTestProcNum~-- continued from previous page}} \\%
\hline \hline%
\endhead% 

\hline \hline%
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{\parbox[top][12pt][c]{\textwidth}{\centering \bf Test Procedure \ThisTestProcNum~-- continues on the next page}} \\%
\hline \hline%
\endfoot%

\hline%
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\parbox[top][12pt][c]{\textwidth}{\centering \bf End of Test Procedure \ThisTestProcNum}} \\%
\hline%
\endlastfoot%
%
% Requirements Validated in this Procedure
%
\hline \hline%
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\parbox[top][12pt][c]{\textwidth}{\centering \bf Requirements Covered by Test Procedure \ThisTestProcNum\setcounter{TestProcItemCounter}{0}}} \\%
\hline \hline%
%{#4}%when this line is uncommented, and two ``\stepcounter...'' lines below are commented out, LaTeX has 10 errors, or it hangs
% the \TestProcedure<> command with hardcoded 2nd column entries, this works just fine when these two lines below are uncommented and ``{#4}'' above is commented
\stepcounter{TestProcItemCounter}~R-\ThisTestProcNum-\theTestProcItemCounter & \parbox[top][12pt][c]{5.0in}{Hardcoded Requirement 1} \\ \hline%
\stepcounter{TestProcItemCounter}~R-\ThisTestProcNum-\theTestProcItemCounter & \parbox[top][12pt][c]{5.0in}{Hardcoded Requirement 2} \\ \hline%
%
% Steps Performed in this Procedure
%
\hline \hline%
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\parbox[top][12pt][c]{\textwidth}{\centering \bf Steps to be Performed for Test Procedure \ThisTestProcNum\setcounter{TestProcItemCounter}{0}}} \\%
\hline \hline%
%{#5}%when this line is uncommented, and two ``\stepcounter...'' lines below are commented out, LaTeX has 10 errors, or it hangs
% the \TestProcedure<> command with hardcoded 2nd column entries, this works just fine when these two lines below are uncommented and ``{#5}'' above is commented
\stepcounter{TestProcItemCounter}~S-\ThisTestProcNum-\theTestProcItemCounter & \parbox[top][42pt][t]{5in}{\vspace{2pt}Hardcoded Step 1} \\ \hline%
\stepcounter{TestProcItemCounter}~S-\ThisTestProcNum-\theTestProcItemCounter & \parbox[top][69pt][t]{5in}{\vspace{2pt}Hardcoded Step 2} \\ \hline%
%
% Noes About This Procedure
%
\hline \hline%
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\parbox[top][12pt][c]{\textwidth}{\centering \bf Notes About Test Procedure \ThisTestProcNum\setcounter{TestProcItemCounter}{0}}} \\%
\hline \hline%
%{#6}%when this line is uncommented, and two ``\stepcounter...'' lines below are commented out, LaTeX has 10 errors, or it hangs
% the \TestProcedure<> command with hardcoded 2nd column entries, this works just fine when these two lines below are uncommented and ``{#6}'' above is commented
\stepcounter{TestProcItemCounter}~N-\ThisTestProcNum-\theTestProcItemCounter & \parbox[top][12pt][c]{5in}{Hardcoded Note 1} \\ \hline%
\stepcounter{TestProcItemCounter}~N-\ThisTestProcNum-\theTestProcItemCounter & \parbox[top][12pt][c]{5in}{Hardcoded Note 2} \\ \hline%
%
\end{longtable}%
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% end of Test Procedure Macro
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\begin{document}
\TestProcedure%[6] Test Procedure Container
% #1 is the test description number, usually built from section number + description within the section
{1.2.3.4.5.6}%#1
% #2 is the test description name
{Test Participant Information}%#2
% #3 is the test description LaTeX label
{lab:testproc_ParticipantInformation}%#3
%
% #4 is the list of requirements covered by this test
%
{%
\tpRqmt{Requirement 1 for realsies}%
\tpRqmt{Requirement 2 for realsies}%
}%#4
% #5 is the list of steps to be performed by this test
{%
\tpStep{Test Step 1 for realsies realsies and dndhshf hfdhc hdhcd  hcdh chd chduic chuihecu hcueh chui hfuie chduich uhcuihc eh cheui hcuih chieu chdwui cwdu uivhdwui cuiwdhcuidwh cuihdui chduih ciuhdui chudiwh cuihd chiud hciudah iuch chdaui cidahcui chadui}{42pt}%
\tpStep{Test Step 2 for realsies realsies and dndhshf hfdhc hdhcd  hcdh chd chduic chuihecu hcueh chui hfuie chduich uhcuihc eh cheui hcuih chieu chdwui cwdu uivhdwui cuiwdhcuidwh cuihdui chduih ciuhdui chudiwh cuihd chiud hciudah iuch chdaui cidahcui chadui}{69pt}%
}%#5
% #6 is the list of notes for this test
{%
\tpNote{Note 1 for realsies}%
\tpNote{Note 2 for realsies}%
}%#6
%%% end TestProcedure[6] test description container
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: Please do not use two-letter font switching such as `\bf` in LaTeX. They were deprecated 20+ years ago.

Comment: This won't minimise work for authors. I guarantee it. How many bad box warnings do you get? This will be too wide for the page.

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me. I don't get any errors. Lots of bad boxes, but no errors.

Comment: Can you simplify this example a bit? I've disentangled `tocloft` but you don't need most of the other stuff. It is just confusing to people trying to help.

Comment: Oh, just drop the curly brackets. You want things expanded here, don't you?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a corrected version of a minimised example. You do not want curly brackets around the variables representing the arguments e.g. `#2` not `{#2}`. You *need* these to be expanded here!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setcounter{LTchunksize}{1000}
%local variables for the \TestProc macro command
\newcounter{TestProcItemCounter}
\newcounter{testprocedure}
\newcommand{\numberedtestprocedure}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{testprocedure}}
\newcommand{\ThisTestProcNum}{?!?num} %this gets set and reset in \TestProc[6]
\newcommand{\tpRqmt}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{TestProcItemCounter}~R-\ThisTestProcNum-\theTestProcItemCounter
  &
  \parbox[top][12pt][c]{5.0in}{#1} \\ \hline
}
\newcommand{\TestProcedure}[2]{%
  \renewcommand{\ThisTestProcNum}{#1}% store away the test description number for use in the macro
  \begin{longtable}[l]{|r|l|}% base table has two columns <item number & item text>
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\parbox[top][12pt][c]{\textwidth}{\centering \bfseries Requirements Covered by Test Procedure \ThisTestProcNum\setcounter{TestProcItemCounter}{0}}} \\
    \hline
    #2
  \end{longtable}%
}

\begin{document}
\TestProcedure
{1.2.3.4.5.6}
{%
  \tpRqmt{Requirement 1 for realsies}%
  \tpRqmt{Requirement 2 for realsies}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO SO MUCH !!!! !! Removing the braces around #4, #5, and #6 in the original MWE work correctly.

Now I can worry about the fine tuning details of making the \hlines not double up on each other :)